# Spring Boot JMS error - No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.jms.config.JmsListenerEndpointRegistry] found for dependency

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-jms

I am trying to migrate existing spring web application (**Spring version 4.1.X**) to Spring boot (**version 1.3**),
I have followed spring documentation **Convert an existing application to Spring Boot** from 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html.

Created a new class ServletInitializer in root package.

```
@SpringBootApplication
  public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder 
    application) {
    return application;
    }
    }
```

**But after starting server I am getting below error. I am not using JMS in the application, Tried excluding JmsAutoConfiguration class even though I am getting below error.**

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'startStopJmsMessageListenerController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.jms.config.JmsListenerEndpointRegistry com.deere.dsfj.utility.jms.StartStopJmsMessageListenerController.registry; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.jms.config.JmsListenerEndpointRegistry] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839) ~[spring-context-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) ~[spring-context-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.7.RELEASE.jar:1.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:760) ~[spring-boot-1.3.7.RELEASE.jar:1.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) ~[spring-boot-1.3.7.RELEASE.jar:1.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:306) ~[spring-boot-1.3.7.RELEASE.jar:1.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:149) ~[spring-boot-1.3.7.RELEASE.jar:1.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:129) ~[spring-boot-1.3.7.RELEASE.jar:1.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:85) ~[spring-boot-1.3.7.RELEASE.jar:1.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169) ~[spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5292) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147) [catalina.jar:8.0.36]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.jms.config.JmsListenerEndpointRegistry com.deere.dsfj.utility.jms.StartStopJmsMessageListenerController.registry; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.jms.config.JmsListenerEndpointRegistry] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.jms.config.JmsListenerEndpointRegistry] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1373) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1119) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    ... 28 common frames omitted
```

**Is there anything I have missed out while migrating Please suggest.**

Comment: Well apparently there is something in your class path that is using JMS... `StartStopJmsMessageListenerController` is a good indication for that.

Comment: **@M.Deinum** In that case **StartStopJmsMessageListenerController** is from **dsfj-spring-boot-util.jar** and error is stating that cannot auto-wire **JmsListenerEndpointRegistry** which is from spring-jms.jar, Even-though something from class path calling the controller it should work properly because both of them from jars.

Comment: No it shouldn't. You don't have JMS but a controller relying on JMS being available is getting instantiated... Exclude that controller if you don't have JMS.

Comment: Tried excluding StartStopJmsMessageListenerController  even though I am getting same error.
**@SpringBootApplication(exclude={JmsAutoConfiguration.class,StartStopJmsMessageListenerController.class})**

Comment: I highly doubt it is the same cause, check your stack trace.

Comment: Checked stack trace still getting same error mentioned above even after excluding StartStopJmsMessageListenerController :
**Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private **

Comment: Still I highly doubt it is the same cause... Check which field on which class... You probably have more classes related to JMS that are detected and thus require JMS.

Comment: Error creating bean with name **'startStopJmsMessageListenerController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private** org.springframework.jms.config.JmsListenerEndpointRegistry com.deere.dsfj.utility.jms.StartStopJmsMessageListenerController.registry; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.jms.config.JmsListenerEndpointRegistry] expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.

Comment: Which indicates you haven't excluded it. If there are multiple component-scans you will have to exclude it from all the scans.

Comment: I am able to resolve the issue by adding componentscan exclude filter.
@ComponentScan(excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value = StartStopJmsMessageListenerController.class))